# NoMethodError in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nomethoderror

Ive started working on an application called Shapado (http://shapado.com) which is running on Ruby with a mongo database in the background.  Im getting the following error when I try to add some data to the database.  I have attached all the relevant files that I think could be the source.

**The error**

```
Processing QuestionsController#tags_for_autocomplete to js (for 93.97.246.67 at 2011-03-31 10:02:00) [GET]
  Parameters: {"tag"=>"backup"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `find_tags' for #<Array:0x7f24f1032448>):
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/associations/proxy.rb:109:in `send'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/associations/proxy.rb:109:in `method_missing'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:37:in `method_missing'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/associations/many_documents_proxy.rb:76:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:184:in `tags_for_autocomplete'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:180:in `tags_for_autocomplete'
  compass (0.10.5) lib/compass/app_integration/rails/actionpack2/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
  warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  haml (3.0.25) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongomapper_ext-0.5.0/lib/mongomapper_ext/file_server.rb:17:in `call'
  app/middlewares/dynamic_domain.rb:17:in `call'
  app/middlewares/mongo_mapper_middleware.rb:24:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

**tags_for_autocomplete method in QuestionsController.rb**

```
def tags_for_autocomplete   
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.js do  
        result = [] 
        if q = params[:tag] 
          result = current_group.questions.find_tags(/^#{Regexp.escape(q.downcase)}/i,  
                                      :group_id => current_group.id,    
                                      :banned => false) 
        end     
        results = result.map do |t| 
          {:caption => "#{t["name"]} (#{t["count"].to_i})", :value => t["name"]}    
        end 
        # if no results, show default tags  
        if results.empty?   
          results = current_group.default_tags.map  {|tag|{:value=> tag, :caption => tag}}  
        end 
        render :json => results 
      end   
    end
```

**/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo_mapper-0.8.6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/associations/proxy.rb:109**

```
protected
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if load_target
      target.send(method, *args, &block)
    end
  end
```

Comment: It looks like `questions` is an `Array` and *MongoMapper* doesn't seem to extend Array with anything else than `to_mongo` and `from_mongo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "current_group.questions.find_tags" with "Question.find_tags" in the 2 locations in code.

As mentioned here:
http://shapado.com/questions/what-is-the-cause-of-the-nomethoderror-when-using-the-search-box-on-the-tags-page

This seems to work for me.